# JavaScript not showing elements that are hidden with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have page that needs to hide all but the first element.
However, the first element continues to be hidden, despite the fact that I have JS telling it to show.

The code works fine on this page:
https://www.dinnerthyme.com/yo-join.aspx
as the first div is shown (even though there is inline css saying "display:none")

However with this test page, it doesn't show any element. If I remove the inline CSS saying "display:none;" of course it will show the first element, but then I cannot be sure that the rest of the JS is working. I'm starting with this code block for testing purposes.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

      <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {


        document.getElementById("one").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
    }       

</script>


  <div>
    <div>
     <div>     
     <h1> Junk </h1>
        <p>stuff </p>


         <div id="one" style="display:none;">    <p>hjdshfjshjshjsdjfskfsdkjf</p></div>
         <div id="two" style="display:none;">    <p>hjdshfjshjshjsdjfskfsdkjf</p></div>
         <div id="three" style="display:none;">    <p>hjdshfjshjshjsdjfskfsdkjf</p></div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be calling `pageLoad()`...?

Comment: Why dont you just write a css code to define the first element to be displayed?

Comment: That is my initial inclination, however the code (which is not mine to begin with) needs to be tested as it is already existing. (there will a bunch of known-working code that already exists that has to be attached)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could change the body tag, use this:

```
<body onload="pageLoad()">
```

But, if it's a partial code and you don't want to change the body tag, simply add this at the end of your code:

```
<script>
  pageLoad();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your body tag call pageLoad

```
<body onload="pageLoad()">
....
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, but it doesn't call it on this page https://www.dinnerthyme.com/yo-join.aspx and yet it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with me, make sure to call your pageLoad() function,

```
<body onload="pageLoad()">
```

see working demo: http://jsbin.com/xeribupora/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Et voila!

```js
function pageLoad() {


        document.getElementById("one").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body onload="pageLoad();">


  <div>
    <div>
     <div>     
     <h1> Junk </h1>
        <p>stuff </p>


         <div id="one"><p>hjdshfjshjshjsdjfskfsdkjf</p></div>
         <div id="two"><p>hjdshfjshjshjsdjfskfsdkjf</p></div>
         <div id="three"><p>hjdshfjshjshjsdjfskfsdkjf</p></div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

In Css

```
 p div:nth-of-type(n+1){
   display:none;
 }
```

In javascript

```
 window.onLoad=function(){
 document.getElementById("one").style.display = "";
 document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";

 };
```

I dont know if this is of much use though.:-/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need to call pageLoad(). Here's one way of doing it using JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
    pageLoad();
},false);
```

Comment: yoooooooooooooo